# Сортировка по двум полям в CakePHP 2.*

Tags: php, сортировка, cakephp

Всем привет. Ребят подскажите как сортировать задачи по 2 полям в пагинации?
Какой код нужен?
Вот что в представлении:

```
<?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('Created', 'По дате создания'); ?>
```

Эта ссылка генерируется для сорт по дате, вот что в контроллере

```
public function index()
{
    $this->Paginator->settings = [
        'limit' => 5,
        'order' => [
            'Task.created' => 'desc'
        ]
    ];
    $tasks = $this->Paginator->paginate('Task');
    $this->set('tasks', $tasks);...
```

Как сделать сортировку по 2 полям? Точнее по Task.created и Task.task_type_id
Заранее спасибо

Comment: метод `sort()`принимает только строковое имя поля, по которому предполагается сортировка. Отсортировать сами данные вы можете по нескольким полям добавив элемент в настройки `order => ['created' => 'desc', 'task_type_id' => 'asc']`, но ссылки на сортировки с помощью хелпера `Paginator->sort()`генерятся только для одного поля, чтобы переключать его порядок (`asc|desc`).

Comment: Если использовать сортировку order => ['created' => 'desc', 'task_type_id' => 'asc'] то все нормально но как потом в представлении сделать ссылку чтобы можно было менять порядок (asc|desc)???

Comment: Дак про то и речь, что генератор стандартных ссылок (метод `sort()`) формирует ссылку для сортировки по одному полю. Ибо для двух полей не понятно как менять сортировку. Когда одно поле тут понятно - он переключает asc-desc, а с двумя полями что он делать должен? Можно ссылку попробовать генерировать вручную, без использования хэлпера. Я с cakephp2 не знаком, как то я с 3й версией начал работать. под рукой нет, посмотреть не могу.